# How force Chrome to use google.com search engine without https

Tags: browser, google-chrome

Chrome's default search engine is https://www.google.com.

How we can force chrome to use http://www.google.com *without `https`*?

I need a solution that allows proxies to rewrite my URLs, but `https` currently makes this impossible...

Comment: Why would you want to? HTTPS makes your traffic secure and keeps the traffic (and searches) away from snooping eyes. Google has gone to HTTPS for everything by default if I recall correctly.

Comment: unfortunately https://google.com is with https filtered in my country

Comment: If you are signed into a google account it appears to default to https I was unable to go to http google while signed in to either of my accounts. try for you self in a new private window.

Comment: @nhutto: [Google redirects HTTP to HTTPS by default](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/10/making-search-more-secure.html).

Comment: that other question's answers don't provide a solution to stop it.  It's annoying 'cos i'm using Privoxy and would like filters to operate on google and they don't 'cos it is using https

Comment: @TomWijsman may as well merge them.

Comment: it may be that @jeremyw has closest to the answer. if his idea of using sslstrip works, it may be an answer.

Comment: One reason to avoid https is speed.  https requests over a satellite link take MUCH longer to complete (factor of 4 or so)  I found this article trying to reduce the amount of https traffic the google search engine uses for stuff that I really don't care if the whole world knows.

Comment: @mehman, does my answer solves your problem? http://superuser.com/a/727691/78851 If so, could you please accept it? :-)

Answer (score 7):

In deed it is possible to configure any browser to use Google without SSL. This technique is called "NORD Technique" (I named it :-))

### Quick (Temporary) Solution

It is sufficient to use "http://www.google.com/search?nord=1&q=%s" as the search engine url.

### Detailed (Permanent) Solution

For the sake of the question, I will make a step by step explanation for Google Chrome.

- Open "Settings" panel.
- Click "Manage search engines..." button under "Search" heading on the settings panel.
- "Search Engines" pane has two sections: "Default search engines" and "Other search engines"
- At the bottom of the "Other search engines" section, you'll see a form which we'll make use to add a new search engine.
  [image: search engine add form]
- In that (above mentioned) form, fill in first two input boxes with whatever you like, I use "Google NonSSL" for the first input and "GoogleNonSsl" for the second. (First one is just a name, and second one is the keyword to use this engine)
- Fill in the last input box with: http://www.google.com/search?nord=1&q=%s
- Press ENTER

At this phase it's enough to use Google w/o SSL by using the keyword you have chosen.

Further, we'll make this new added search engine the default search engine, so your all search es within the omnibar will use non-ssl Google. To do this, find the relevant listing row on the "Other search engines" list, hover it and click revealed "Make default" link.

That's all.

Answer (score 2):

You can manage your search engines in Google Chrome by going into the Wrench menu, selecting Preferences, and then clicking on *Manage Search Engines* (towards the bottom in the Search section).

Comment: how can manage search engine?

Comment: Follow the directions and you'll see. Just click on a selection and edit it to your heart's content.

Comment: ok, but redirect to https

Comment: Google is also redirecting to HTTPS itself; they documented that in [this web post](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/10/making-search-more-secure.html). There is some good discussion about how to turn off the Google redirection [here](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/websearch/how-do-iusing-google-search/XqaV7oi_iTE). I found these by doing a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+https+redirect).

Comment: @david I have no "preferences" option so you mean http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95653  the wrench then options/preferences, then basic, then manage search engines. anyhow, it doesn't stop it from going to https for google.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable SSL if you are signed into your Google account. However, you can configure your network's DNS records using the `NoSSLSearch` option. See [SSL Search](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173733) at Google Help for more information.

Comment: says about using DNS to point to nosslsearch.google.com  Looks promising, but if I go to that  URL Directly it still goes to https. maybe i'm doing something wrong there but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Yes. That is how DNS/CNAME works. You can't do the redirection yourself.

Comment: what do you mean? I tried it in the hosts file it also didn't work.  so if i can't do it directly and can't do it in the hosts file, where would i do it?

Comment: With an actual DNS server.

Comment: any suggestions of a quick freeware dns server I could set up?

Answer (score 0):

Google has stopped allowing non-ssl connections to `www.google.com` when you are signed in. The only way that you can access `http://www.google.com` is to be signed out.

For the sake of my own curiosity, why would you want to be connected to http:

[Source](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/10/making-search-more-secure.html)

Comment: "With SSL, content filters and proxies on your network may not be able to see or modify the search query or Google’s response." -[Google Help](http://superuser.com/a/399923/100787)

Comment: cos i'm playing with privoxy and google is my homepage, and privoxy (and perhaps other web proxies too like squid), doesn't work with https

Comment: Gotcha. Can you update your question for this as you'll end up getting a lot of answers like mine if you're trying to use it via proxies.

Comment: they can write their curiousity in a comment, but really the question isn't how do i do it with a proxy. though if all direct answers are exhausted i'd give such an approach a look. iglvzx may be onto something, though testing it, setting up a DNS server which i've never done before,looks like a big project, not a 5/10min thing to set up!

Comment: Untested but theoretically possible: Your Computer -> Privoxy -> SSLStrip -> Your Router. SSLStrip should make the site visible to Privoxy's filtering.

Answer (score -1):

Use an *Incognito-mode* window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+N</kbd>.

Comment: You would think that HTTPS would specifically be used in the “privacy” mode. :roll:

Comment: Afaik it is not an answer to the original question.