# Can I force Google Chrome or Google Search to not use HTTPS with google.com?

Tags: google-chrome, privacy, ssl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How force Chrome to use google.com search engine without https](https://superuser.com/questions/377398/how-force-chrome-to-use-google-com-search-engine-without-https)

Every time I go to www.google.com  in Chrome it goes to `HTTPS://www.google.com`, which happens when signed in.

I don't know if it's just Chrome that does this, but I'd like it to just go to `http://www.google.com` not `https`.

Is there a way to set this?

Comment: You are supposed to give a bounty in that case, or sufficiently make your question different. In it's current form, it's a duplicate and answers can be merged...