# How to search non ssl google?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, ssl, https

Even when I visit `nosslsearch.google.com` I ultimately get redirected to `https://www.google.com`. Why is this? (I'm not signed in to google, and I'm entering these in the urlbar, not the search plugins.)

I've tried Firefox 23 on both Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7, with the same results. I've also tried Chrome on Windows 7 with the same result. I've tried using Firefox in safe mode with all addons disabled, and clean profiles and clean installs of Firefox.

Surely the purpose of the nosslsearch site is to allow non-HTTPS searches, but using the firefox console, I see that it first redirects me to `http://www.google.com` which subsequently just redirects me to `https://www.google.com`. Why is it doing this?

(I need non-HTTPS search as HTTPS are blocked)

Comment: BTW do you use `nonsslsearch.google.com` or `nosslsearch.google.com` ???

Comment: @Rik sorry that was just a typo, fixed now in question: `nosslsearch.google.com`

Comment: @fpghost You can use `http://216.239.32.20`. That one seems to work. I think Google is messing with some things. 216.239.32.20 is the IP of nosslsearch.google.com.

Comment: You can always add `216.239.32.20 google.com www.google.com` in your hosts file so you always get to the http and you never use the https variant. It's not perfect but works.

Comment: A current and working solution can be found here: http://superuser.com/a/727691/78851

Answer (score 2):

Normally private browsing will help you to browse without ssl, it will  allows you to browse the Internet without saving any information or data about which sites you have visited.

You Can turn off SSl by doing this(assuming you already sign-out of your Google account)

1. Navigate to Tools → Options
2. Click on Encryption tab
3. Remove the checks from next to "Use SSL 3.0" and "Use TLS 1.0."
4. Click Ok and exit

For firefox 23.0

1.Type `about:config`

2.Find  `security.tls.version.max`

[image]

3.Change the respective values to "0"

```
security.tls.version.min = 0
security.tls.version.max = 0
```

4.Restart the browser to make changes effect.

Normally google uses SSL 3.0 so you can disable and run it.

Comment: Wouldn't this disabled SSL on *all* websites?

Comment: Tools ---> Options in Firefox 23?

Comment: @fpghost added answer for firefox 23,in firefox 23 the encryption tab is absent,added alternative to it

Comment: If you want to do it for another browsers you should 
add a line to the hosts file:

216.239.32.20 google.com www.google.com

See http://geeks.im/how-to-stop-and-disable-google-ssl-https-search/?replytocom=99#respond