# How do I stop google redirecting search to https?

Tags: google-chrome, https, google-search

Over roughly the past 2 weeks Google search has either been painfully slow to return results or simply aborts after 30 seconds or so with 'page can't be displayed'.

I then noticed that the search page was using https:// instead of the usual http://

NB: This occurs when I am NOT logged into Chrome.

How do I disable this and go back to **http**://google.com ?  I simply don't need or care about my search input strings being possibly visible to someone.

I have nothing to hide and have not felt the need to type my net banking details into the google search box any time lately.

The inconvenience of a painfully slow search so far outweighs this limited privacy benefit it is ridiculous.

I am well aware of the value of HTTPS and rely on it for my internet banking among other things.  Obviously HTTPS imposes an overhead and at least it should be able to be turned off for things like search input.

I've researched and found information about a Chrome search option that did disable this, but this option no longer seems to exist.

This seems to be a worrying trend of late where Google seems to believe that they know better than I do (or you) in regard to how we want to use the web.

They have enforced HTTPS in a scenario where it is not required at a large cost of usability

Comment: what benchmarks do you have to indicate that HTTPS is slowing the session down in a noticeable fashion? SSL has some processing overhead, but nothing like what you are describing. it will not slow the feeding or retreival of data across the wire; it will just take a few extra cycles to decode the data, and the speed of that operation has everything to do with your PC, and almost nothing to do with the network or the server. do other sites SSL pages cause you significant slowdowns?

Comment: @Frank Thomas: HTTPS is the only change I have seen in the time since the performance issues have occurred.  Opera using http in the same time period did not have these performance issues.

Comment: Note, you're probably using [SPDY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY) which is usually [faster](http://www.favbrowser.com/spdy-vs-http-benchmarks/)

Comment: It's been in the news lately that Google is implementing major revisions to its search algorithms. I, too, have noticed a major slowdown in Google search response. This has nothing whatever to do with https.

Answer (score 5):

You could try `http://nosslsearch.google.com`. If that one also redirects you to `https:www.google.com` you have the same problem as [here](https://superuser.com/questions/646022/how-to-search-non-ssl-google)

Then you can add `216.239.32.20 google.com www.google.com` to your hosts file.
You can't use https with google anymore.

You can also use `http://216.239.32.20` for non-ssl searches.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I have the same issue as you link to. I'll try out the hosts solution or direct IP address.

Comment: `http://nosslsearch.google.com` is broken as of Jan 2017.

Answer (score 4):

It's now official -- Google doesn't support non-https searches anymore:

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com.au/2013/09/google-encrypted-search-for-everyone.html

Yuck, had to switch all my company 8K users default search to Bing, due to filtering requirements.

I can hear the laughs come out loud from Redmond...

Comment: No no I don’t think anyone cares you switched to bing to allow inspection of employee search queries. In fact people are probably cheering.

Answer (score 0):

> Over roughly the past 2 weeks Google search has either been painfully slow to return results 
>   or simply aborts after 30 seconds or so with 'page can't be displayed'.
>
> NB: This occurs when I am NOT logged into Chrome.

I have noticed the same, however I don't believe it is due to encryption (https) ... I have been using the encrypted search site since it came online (some years now) and I have never noticed the difference vs the unencrypted site.  I've used Google since the beginning and I have never before seen it so predictably unresponsive for so long a time.

I initially thought Google's slowness was related to the Firefox v23.01 release, but IE10 barfs on Google searches too, and now you say it is happening with Chrome.  There hasn't been any mention of a large denial of service attack against Google, but that would be my bet as to why this is happening.

Comment: Oops ... actually you said *NOT* with Chrome.  Maybe Google did something that breaks everyone's' browsers except their own.

Answer (score 0):

Operax64(12.17) is doing google.co.uk searches just fine without ssl. Go to the site, manually remove the ssl string from address, then make a thumbnail of the site by dragging it over to speed dial.

its not perfect, and thats why im here looking for further much needed anti-google solutions. Every other search widget in opera will use ssl. Only way is to manually force.

Answer (score 0):

lastest way is changing the useragent
learn [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19021147/)
should set chrome version < 15

make a shortcut of chrome browser
right-click > properties
change `Target`

for example :
`...\chrome.exe`

to this:
`...\chrome.exe --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT) AppleWebKit/537.9 Chrome/15.0 Safari/537.9"`

then google will search without SSL